# Orléans: endgame - beneficial deeds and development track

Tags: orleans

Recently played Orleans with a board gaming group here in Japan and ran into something interesting with the rules.

We first played it a month ago, but this month when we played it, they told me got the rules wrong the first time. Specifically, it was claimed that:

> the person highest on the development track gets all of the citizens from the unfinished beneficial deeds at the end of the game.

Can someone show me where in the rule book this is? In the rules from BGG, I see

> The game ends after 18 rounds. Before you proceed with the scoring, the player who has built the most Trading
>   Stations receives the remaining Citizen Tile. If there is a tie, no player receives the tile.

But does this mean all of the citizen tiles or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The player would just receive the one remaining citizen tile that isn't on the game boards.**

The game comes with 14 Citizen Tiles. In the [rulebook](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/107664/english-rules) under setup, section 8 (labeled page 12):

> Place 13 **Citizen Tiles** on the marked spaces on the game board and the **“Beneficial Deeds” board**. Put the remaining tile on the table.

The part we are concerned with is the last sentence, where there is one Citizen that doesn't go onto any board space. On page 19, under final scoring:

> ..the player who built the **most Trading Stations** receives the remaining **Citizen Tile**.

So the player who built the most Trading Stations gets the Citizen that was left off the board during setup.

---

In relation to the rule regarding the person highest on the Development Track getting any Citizens tiles from the Beneficial Deeds board, it doesn't exist. Those Citizen Tiles stay on the Beneficial Deeds board and do not get scored at the end of the game.

Comment: Interesting... there may be a mistranslation in the Japanese rules in that case (English native speaker here -- first time I translated the rules on the fly; second play a month later and they tell me there's some sort of rule like that. Seemed off).

Comment: Supplemental information: the Japanese rules were indeed mistranslated (http://www.arclight.co.jp/ag/index.php?page=errata&code=LG-0127 ). The page explains that it should be just the one ( as the German and English rules state)... but in their printed version it *stated* all.